# Cannot figure out why this happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

While installing packages via NPM, This error was showing.
Please help me out Why showing this error.

✅ Using react v18

````
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2
npm WARN Found: react@18.0.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   11 more (@restart/hooks, @restart/ui, @testing-library/react, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2
npm WARN node_modules/@restart/ui/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr
npm WARN   @react-aria/ssr@"^3.0.1" from @restart/ui@1.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@restart/ui
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@restart/ui/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr
npm WARN     @react-aria/ssr@"^3.0.1" from @restart/ui@1.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@restart/ui ```
````

Comment: *peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2* --- The ssr library you're using does not support react 18 yet. This is going to be pretty common since 18 is so new. You'll have to wait until they publish an update to support it

Comment: But still getting theses warning: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2:

Comment: This is already opened as [a Github issue](https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/issues/2800).